# i set it , but it doesn't confirm UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm set tableview datasource but it doesn't recognize with his erorr
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var contact : [pedped]=[]

        let asghar = pedped()
        asghar.nmae="asghar "
        asghar.lname="ghasemi"
        asghar.image="asghar"

        let akbar = pedped()
        akbar.nmae="akbar "
        akbar.lname="askj"
        akbar.image="asgkajsjkashar"


        contact.append(asghar)
        contact.append(akbar)



        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return contact.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)as!custom
            let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]
            cell.lablename.text = contacts.nmae
            cell.lastnamelable.text = contacts.lname
            return cell
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you set it? Not in that code. Also, that code does not conform to the uitableview protocols because (according to the indentation) the datasource functions are within the viewDidLoad function. They need to be outside of that.

Answer (score 1):

Although `ViewController` conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`, you are implementing the methods in *wrong* place. You have to remove them outside `viewDidLoad`.

Also, make sure that the table view data source/delegate is connected to the view controller itself, whether from the interface build or from the code:

```
// create an IBOutlet for the table view then:
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work 100% but it at least shows you a better way to organize your code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var contact = [pedped]() // Int

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let asghar = pedped()
        asghar.nmae="asghar "
        asghar.lname="ghasemi"
        asghar.image="asghar"

        let akbar = pedped()
        akbar.nmae="akbar "
        akbar.lname="askj"
        akbar.image="asgkajsjkashar"


        contact.append(asghar)
        contact.append(akbar)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource 

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contact.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)as!custom
        let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]
        cell.lablename.text = contacts.nmae
        cell.lastnamelable.text = contacts.lname
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
   // Put any UITableViewDelegate functions here
}
```